# Mixed case regular expression replacement, in Vim

Tags: regular-expression

I often run into a situation where I have a file with a lot of mixed case. For example,

```
CamelCase and camelCase
```

I'm looking for a Vim regular expression replacement to produce,

```
AnotherCase and anotherCase
```

Right now I do this in two steps after visually selecting the lines,

```
:s/CamelCase/AnotherCase/g
:s/camelCase/anotherCase/g
```

Is this possible in one replacement step, or should I look into other options like a function in `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using `:Subvert` via Tim Pope's [Abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish)

```
:%S/camelCase/anotherCase/g
```

[Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Supercharged substitution with :Subvert](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/supercharged-substitution-with-subvert/)

Comment: This plugin made that so easy. I didn't look under the hood, but thought I'd try `:%S/CamelCase/AnotherCase/g`, however it only replaces `CamelCase` and left `camelCase` as is. No big deal, just something to remember.

Comment: It's likely using smartcase or something to that effect so that any upper case characters are required to be upper case but lower case can be capitalized as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You also have the venerable [keepcase](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=6).

With

```
:SubstituteCase#\ctoto\(Titi\)tata#\1Tutu#g
```

you'll obtain:

```
 totoTitiTata -> titiTutu
 TotoTitiTata -> TitiTutu
 tototititata -> tititutu
 tototitiTata -> titiTutu
 TototitiTata -> TitiTutu
```